# Is there any way to check if an ObjectInputStream has an object waiting to be read?

Tags: java, networking

I am working on a simple chat box between two clients that feed strings through a server. So far, I am using the ObjectInputStream in java, and I want to check if the stream currently has any objects waiting to be read. I know that the method "reader.readObject()" waits until there is an object to be sent, but is there any way to check if the input stream is currently holding a value?

Answer (score 0):

There is `available()` method in ObjectInputStream that returns the number of *bytes* that can be read from the stream, although i'm not sure how you can check if there is an object waiting to be read